# display 360 degree image in a web page

Tags: html, aframe

i'm trying to add 360 degree image to my web page (panorama image)

i've try this , but it just display a black screen 
[demo

```html
 
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

   <a-scene>
       <img id="panorama" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/suKT3.jpg">
      <a-sky  src="#panorama" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
```

][1]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: edited , sorry ,

Comment: Still not there yet...we need to see the code NOT working in a demo.

Comment: updated , please let me know if there is any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I think there might be an issue with your image or the imgur link because of some x-frame options. Check this out. This is the example taken from [aframe](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/sky/)

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
 <a-scene>
      <a-sky src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/v1.0.4/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>

      <a-text font="kelsonsans" value="Puy de Sancy, France" width="6" position="-2.5 0.25 -1.5"
              rotation="0 15 0"></a-text>
    </a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code snippets with 360 image view and zoom in and zoom out features.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>360 Views</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
      <script>
        window.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
          // small increments for smoother zooming
          const delta = event.wheelDelta / 120 / 10;
          var mycam = document.getElementById("cam").getAttribute("camera");
          var finalZoom =
            document.getElementById("cam").getAttribute("camera").zoom + delta;
      
          // limiting the zoom
          if (finalZoom < 0.5) finalZoom = 0.5;
          if (finalZoom > 2) finalZoom = 2;
          mycam.zoom = finalZoom;
      
          document.getElementById("cam").setAttribute("camera", mycam);
        });
      </script>
      <a-scene>
        <a-entity
          id="cam"
          camera="zoom: 1"
          look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true"
        ></a-entity>
        <!-- my pano image stuff -->
        <a-assets>
          <img id="skyTexture" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/v1.0.4/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg" />
        </a-assets>
        <a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>
      </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <title>360 Views</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
  
      <script>
        window.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
          const delta = event.wheelDelta / 120 / 10;
          var mycam = document.getElementById("cam").getAttribute("camera");
          var finalZoom =
            document.getElementById("cam").getAttribute("camera").zoom + delta;
      
          // limiting the zoom
          if (finalZoom < 0.5) finalZoom = 0.5;
          if (finalZoom > 2) finalZoom = 2;
          mycam.zoom = finalZoom;
      
          document.getElementById("cam").setAttribute("camera", mycam);
        });
      </script>
      <a-scene>
        <a-entity
          id="cam"
          camera="zoom: 1"
          look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true"
        ></a-entity>
        <a-assets>
          <img id="skyTexture" crossorigin="anonymous"src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596263576925-d90d63691097?q=80&w=1622&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
        </a-assets>
        <a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>
      </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```